# Session to display current login User

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my code. I want to make a Seesion which display the current login user

Thank you !

```
$link = mysql_connect($DB_server, $DB_user, $DB_password,$DB_name);
mysql_select_db('linux', $link) or die(mysql_error());

$uid = 0;
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $uid = $_GET["id"];
}


$profilname = mysql_query("SELECT U_Benutzername ,U_ID FROM u_user WHERE U_ID = '$uid'");
$emailadresse =mysql_query("SELECT U_login ,U_ID FROM u_user WHERE U_ID = '$uid'");
$_SESSION['profilname'] = $profilname;
$_SESSION['email'] =$emailadresse;

echo "Benutzername: $profilname";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Email: $profilname";
```

Comment: the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated and it will be deleted - if you have to use structual PHP use `mysqli_*`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You used `mysqli_connect`, right (responding to what you posted as an 'answer')? You cannot use `mysql_` and `mysqli_` together.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo...

```
$lid = $_GET["id"];
```

should probably be

```
$uid = $_GET["id"];
```

change your mysql query to:

```
if($uid!=0) {
    $ref = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_user WHERE U_ID = '$uid'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($ref);
    $profilname = $row["U_Benutzername"];
    $emailadresse= $row["U_login"];
    $_SESSION['profilname'] = $profilname;
    $_SESSION['email'] =$emailadresse;
}
```

to display it:

```
echo $_SESSION['profilname'];
```

BUT:
You wont get far with this, this is mysql_-code and its deprecated.
You *have* to use mysqli in newer PHP-Versions.
http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, i correct it.
Any idea to solve my problem ?

Comment: if it helped you, you can gracefully accept the answer:-)

Comment: @cari It sounds like to me that this didn't solve the OP's problem (despite them not telling you that).

Comment: oh ok, missed that. added the relevant parts;-)

Comment: It might be valid PHP since I don't normally program in PHP, but shouldn't `$ref = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_user WHERE U_ID = '$uid'");` be `$ref = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_user WHERE U_ID = '. $uid .'");` instead?

Comment: no, its ok like this

Answer (score 0):

Change `$lid = $_GET["id"];` to `$uid = $_GET["id"];`, and it also is a good idea to sanitize the data from `$_GET`,